# tvOS - TVML data binding with carousel element

Tags: data-binding, carousel, tvos, tvml

I tried to create a template dynamically with the use of binding, and everything go fine with the element "grid" or "shelf", but when i use the element "carousel", the output is empty.

I've created a sample project on GitHub that demonstrate the problem: https://github.com/christrato/TVMLTestApp

The code is identically for both the example (grid and layout), instruction how to execute the test in readme file.

Maybe a bug of the carousel layout, or i need extra settings for data binding and carousel?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am seeing the same thing. The carousel is taking up space, but not showing the images & titles.

Comment: Same here, any solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let template = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <document>
    <stackTemplate>
    <banner>
    <title>TVML Test</title>
    </banner>
    <collectionList>
        <shelf >
        <prototypes>
                <lockup prototype="home">
                    <img binding="@src:{thumb};" width="350" height="250"/>
                    <title binding="textContent:{title};"/>
                </lockup>
        </prototypes>
                <section binding = "items:{images};" />


        </shelf>

    </collectionList>
    </stackTemplate>
    </document>`;
```

please use this code then carousel works. I replace carousel with shelf and section. it worked for me